# Writing custom metrics to InfluxDB with Graphite

Tags: java, scala, influxdb, gatling, graphite

Gatling reported metrics are not sufficient for me, and thus, I calculate **additional** metrics during execution.

Is there a way to report these additional metrics using Gatling's built-in support for Graphite & InfluxDB integration?

If not, I have to report these values myself? for example in the `after` block:

```
  setUp(
    secenario1
      .inject(atOnceUsers(10))
  ).assertions(assertions())

  after {
    // use influx DB client and send the additional values.
    reportMetricsToInfluxDB()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gatling doesn't provide send any custom values to Influxdb. You can get [influxdb client library](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java/tree/master/client-scala) and then realize what you want.